# Is there a way to STOP ADB from logging calls from certain sources, rather than just filtering them out?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, monitor

I'm trying to debug an application on a Galaxy S7, and it's almost impossible to get a useful log because the device spams the same log call hundreds of thousands of times in a few seconds:

```
07-31 10:49:33.962: D/NetworkStatsCollection(3838): getHistory:mUID 10158 isVideoCallUID: false
```

This pushes the useful log calls out of the log stack before I can read them or even copy and paste them.
I've used filters for years on my previous Android devices to only see the calls that are relevant to me, but the problem is that this only seems to control what is shown in Monitor rather than limiting is actually being processed as a log call.

Is it possible to completely block certain calls?

Answer (score 1):

Use `logcat --prune` command to set up white and black lists of processes.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html :

> You provide a mixed content of `<white>` and `~<black>` list entries, where  or  can be a UID, UID/PID or /PID. With guidance from the logcat statistics (`logcat -S`), one can consider adjustments to the white and black lists for purposes such as:
>   Give the highest longevity to specific logging content through UID selections.
>   Blacklist who (UID) or what (PID) is consuming these resources to help increase the logspan so you can have more visibility into the problems you are diagnosing.
>   By default the logging system automatically blacklists the worst offender in the log statistics dynamically to make space for new log messages. Once it has exhausted the heuristics, the system prunes the oldest entries to make space for the new messages.
>
> Adding a whitelist protects your Android Identification number (AID), which becomes the processes' AID and GID from being declared an offender, and adding a blacklist helps free up space before the worst offenders are considered. You can choose how active the pruning is, and you can turn pruning off so it only removes content from the oldest entries in each log buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try next setting for the logcat?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't see that option anywhere in Monitor. When I connect this device it also does not show a list of running applications, which my previous devices did. As a workaround for this issue I've changed from using Monitor to just calling adb in a shell, and silencing the non-relevant logs:

    adb logcat myTag:V System.err:V *:S